# Forwarding Traffic To Particular IP using IPTABLES

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip

I am dealing with 3 machines (VMs):

- A: 172.20.10.1 (Client)
- B: 172.20.10.2 (Original Server)
- C: 172.20.10.5 (Redirect Server)

Now I want A to visit B and B to forward that to C.

I was able to achieve this by using:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.10.5:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But now I want to do this for one IP only (I.E) 172.20.10.1 to 172.20.10.5 when it tries to access 172.20.10.2. I have already tried [The answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156151/iptables-routing-incoming-ip-to-another-destination-ip-question?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

And yes, `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` is also set.

Comment: This is a crosspost of https://superuser.com/questions/1331115/forwarding-traffic-to-particular-ip-using-iptables. Make up your mind where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add something to match the ip you want the rule to match:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 172.20.10.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.10.5:80
```

Comment: This doesn't work..

Comment: I've copied my answer, with a follow-up to your comment on the cross-posted copy.